# dynamic matched sampling to distinguish homophily and influence

Tags: social-network

I am trying to understand what dynamic matched sampling is and how this can be applied to
understand influence and homophily on social networks.

Could anyone explain me why this is relevant or could you tell me materials to help
me to understand this approach?

http://www.pnas.org/content/106/51/21544.abstract